# Querying a database with an array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to query my database with an array, I'm trying to count the number of rows returned from the query for each country in my database, and also count the rows for each of these countries with a digit equalling 1. Using the following code:

```
<?php

include ('mysqli_connect.php'); // indclude mysql connection functions
 
$countries = array('united states','canada','united kingdom');
 
foreach($countries as $country){
        //e.g. $r_spain holds the results from the query below with spain as $country
        $r_.$country = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM feelings WHERE country = '$country' AND digit='1'");
 
        //loop through the results
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_.$country, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($r_.$country);
                echo $country."=".$rowCount;   
        }      
}
 
?>
```

This is the error message I get:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class
> mysqli_result could not be converted
> to string in
> /home2/designwr/public_html/uwe/notalone/updates/percentage.php
> on line 9

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you using mysqli as opposed to mysql? Mysqli isn't really used as much...

Comment: i don't know :) thats how i was taught it, is it bad?

Comment: very wrong ... mysqli is the OO way to connect to MySQL, so it's very well the #1-choice now.

Comment: I think you should use mysqli or PDO and take advantage of the prepared statements they offer.

Comment: I am wondering, is there at least one among those mysqli propagandists who will propose a proper solution using prepared statements. I am afraid none of them using it in real ;)

Comment: thanks for all the useful tips guys! solved :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a string concatenation for your variable name: `$r_.$country` is the result of the two strings added together.

I would suggest using an array for the result set like:

```
$r = array();     // after $countries
....
    $r[$country] = mysqli_query......
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Change:

$r_.$country

to:

${'r_'.$country}
```

And delete the loop (not it's contents):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_.$country, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

So in the end the code would look like this:

```
<?php

include ('mysqli_connect.php'); // indclude mysql connection functions

$countries = array('united states','canada','united kingdom');

foreach($countries as $country){
        //e.g. $r_spain holds the results from the query below with spain as $country
        ${'r_'.$country} = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM feelings WHERE country = '$country' AND digit='1'");
        $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows(${'r_'.$country});
        echo $country."=".$rowCount;   
}

?>
```

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 0):

I take it line 9 is

```
 $r_.$country = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM feelings WHERE country = '$country' AND digit='1'");
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `$r_.$country = mysqli_query(...);` but that's invalid syntax. Use an array:

```
$r[$country] = mysqli_query(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the manual on [mysqli/query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). There you will find simple working examples to get the basics straight. counting is done by the [count statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) in the SQL-request.